# How do I execute command from history without printing it again in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, history

```
$ echo hello; cd ~/Docs    
hello

$ !! 
echo hello; cd ~/Docs
hello
```

I want to get `hello` and execute the change directory after typing `!!` without re-showing `echo hello; cd ~/Docs`,  again.

**Edit:**

fc only works for one command, but doesn't execute the full line from terminal.  The same for `!!` or `$(!!)`, they don't work.  I tried `stty -echo`, but the same - it only hides typing `!!`, but still shows the command.  The closest solution I had is to store that command then run it from a `script.sh`, but it will still show that it's running a `script.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following function that is loaded with your bash config (for instance in `.bashrc`):

```
rpt() {
  IFS=';' read -r -a array <<< "$(fc -ln -1)"
  for element in "${array[@]}"
  do
    $element
  done
}
```

Run the command `rpt` to execute the function.

This reads the last command string into an array, and splits it at the `;` signs, and each element in the array (each command) is run separately.

For this to work, the `;` is a reserved character, that can not under any circumstance be used in printed strings etc.

This is a limitation you have to accept for this solution, but I consider it "good enough" to work.

Comment: but only executes one command, not a line from terminal, for example:  echo hello; cd ~/Docs;.  Now, if you run $( fc -ln -1 );  it will result in executing echo only,  resulting in hello; cd ~/Docs;.  I want it to execute the full line including the cd command.

Comment: @muru I've edited my answer completely - you might want to remove earlier comments.